# understanding javascript objects vs map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object-literal

I've been reading about javascript lately and I understand that most things are objects, functions, objects, arrays, etc. So I tried implementing something today, and I don't understand why it wasn't behaving as I was expecting it to. A little clarification would be nice.

I was trying to map some strings, to other strings, so I tried an object literal approach:

```
var stringMap = {
 'string1': 'string1 equivalent',
 'string2': 'string2 equivalent',
 //etc..
};
```

when I tried to do this:

```
var mapString = stringMap['string1'];
```

I got undefined. I, then, updated the object to this:

```
var stringMap = {
 return: {
  'string1': 'string1 equivalent',
  'string2': 'string2 equivalent',
  //etc..
 }
};
```

same result, undefined. Then I did this:

```
var stringMap = [];
stringMap['string1'] = 'string1 equivalent';
stringMap['string2'] = 'string2 equivalent';
//etc..
```

and this time, this worked:

```
var mapString = stringMap['string1'];
```

if everything is an object, why didn't my first 2 object literal attempts work? Was my sytanx wrong.

---

***UPDATE***

sorry guys, after writing this question, I realized what I did wrong. 
I said that I tried the following with the object literal:

```
var mapString = stringMap['string1'];
```

however, this is ***wrong***, what I tried was the following:

```
var stringVal = 'string1';
var mapString = stringMap.stringVal;
```

I will keep this question open and accept an answer though, because The answers are helpful still!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a variable with `var`, the return value is `undefined`.

```
var x = 5;
//=> undefined
```

To add to the confusion, `console.log` will also return `undefined` but it will output values to stdout

```
console.log(x);
// stdout: 5
//=> undefined
```

With that said, your code works fine

```
var stringMap = {
 'string1': 'string1 equivalent',
 'string2': 'string2 equivalent',
 //etc..
};
//=> undefined

var mapString = stringMap['string1'];
//=> undefined

console.log(mapString);
// stdout: 'string1 equivalent'
//=> undefined
```

You could also write

```
var mapString = stringMap.string1;
//=> undefined

console.log(mapString);
// stdout: 'string1 equivalent'
//=> undefined
```

Or log the value directly

```
console.log(stringMap.string1);
// stdout:'string1 equivalent'
//=> undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll go through your examples one by one:

```
var mapString = stringMap['string1'];
```

The above is fine. To actually log the variable, you should do `console.log(mapString)`.

```
var stringMap = {
 return: {
  'string1': 'string1 equivalent',
  'string2': 'string2 equivalent',
  //etc..
 }
};
```

The above is a syntax error. Won't work anywhere.

```
var stringMap = [];
stringMap['string1'] = 'string1 equivalent';
stringMap['string2'] = 'string2 equivalent';
```

On the above, you're monkey-patching properties to the Array instance itself; you're not actually adding elements *into* the Array. To add something inside of the Array, you can use various methods like `unshift`, `push`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Show undefined in console but value of `string1` actually assigned to stringMap variable.

Try below code in console:

```
var stringMap = {
 'string1': 'string1 equivalent',
 'string2': 'string2 equivalent'
};

var mapString = stringMap['string1'];

mapString // Print value in console
```

Value assigned to **variable** can be used using square braces `[]` but object property can be use using dot operator `.`

```
var stringVal = 'string1';
// var mapString = stringMap.stringVal; // won't work because 'stringVal' is variable
var mapString = stringMap[stringVal]; // Work
```

Answer (score 1):

Since everything is an object instead of using

```
 var stringMap = {
     'string1': 'string1 equivalent',
     'string2': 'string2 equivalent',
 //etc..
};
```

you can instantiate your object as

```
var stringMap = {
    string1: 'string1Value',
    string2: 'string2Value,
}
```

or even

```
var stringMap = {};
stringMap.string1 = 'string1Value';
stringMap.string2 = 'string2Value';
```

To access the object's properties (in this case the strings inside stringMap) you can use bracket notation

```
var x = stringMap['string1'];
```

or dot notation

```
var x = stringMap.string1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet from Console , it might help you

```
var stringMap = {
 'string1': 'string1 equivalent',
 'string2': 'string2 equivalent'
};
```

### undefined // Shows undefined but actually value is assigned

```
stringMap['string1']
```

### "string1 equivalent"

```
stringMap.string1
```

### "string1 equivalent"

```
stringMap[string1]
VM165:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: string1 is not defined(…)
```